# Why won't print in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, inputstream, bufferedreader

The code below doesn't print in jsp (the out.println in while{} ) but it works like a charm in  Java program. Can you please explain me why won't print in jsp and what should I change in code? Thank you!

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ page import="java.io.BufferedReader" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.IOException" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.InputStreamReader" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.PrintWriter" %>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.ServletException" %>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" %>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest" %>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse" %>
<%@ page import="java.net.*" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Test

<%try{
URL url = new URL("http://gesi-ro-test.banat.enelro:8010/dynamic/gesi/ri/elab/endcallrequest/wind.ser?id=008201dfa306f4a6&es=&is=2011/04/20%2013:09:46.593&rt=RE");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

String inputLine = "";
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
    {
        out.println(inputLine);
    }
in.close();
}catch(Exception e){
    out.println(e);
    }%>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe because you didn't defined "out"?

Comment: Out *is* (implicitly) defined to be the JSP output stream (writes to the client)...

Comment: But if I write anything it prints, for example:  out.println("hello"); It prints.

Comment: Are you sure that `in` contains any data?

Comment: Could it just be buffered? Is there any input data at all? Also print to System.err for debugging.

Comment: Yes, in contains data, for example the same code in simple java code: http://prntscr.com/e58jt

Comment: Double check the **url**. I'm sure that issue is with URL.

Comment: Ok, attach a debugger and see what happens...

Comment: There is definitely an issue with the URL, if I provide my own **http://gagandeepbali.uk.to/**, then the above JSP is working, as good as ever.

Comment: Gagandeep Bali: my URL returns a XML, I think that is the problem, XML and jsp something. I'm not familiar with JSP, I like writing my java code into servlets but now I must write it in jsp.  

Mathias Schwarz: thank you for trying to help!

Comment: Check the URL deeply. There may be some problem with that URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your url again. I tried your code with another site and it works:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>


<%@ page import="java.io.BufferedReader" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.IOException" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.InputStreamReader" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.PrintWriter" %>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.ServletException" %>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" %>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest" %>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse" %>
<%@ page import="java.net.*" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<%
URL url;
try {
    url = new URL("http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            url.openStream()));

    String inputLine = "";
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
%>

<c:out value="<%=inputLine%>"/>

<%
    }
    in.close();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

%>

</body>
</html>
```

Personally, I dont like to put a lot of "if", "while" command in the jsp file (it will makes your system later become a big mess), so, try to handle eveything in your business logic and then send the result to the jsp as a attribute

Comment: Thai Tran:  I tried with this url: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml. Why do I get this error?  java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host: connect

Comment: can you connect to it on a browser? anyway, it does not matter with my url. Try it with your url to see whether the code works or not

Comment: Yes i can connect on a browser

Comment: @mamba - That exception is due to an intervening firewall, or if an intermediate router is down.

Comment: So it seems that I have a network problem(firewall is turned off). I will test the code on other pc and I will let you know if it works or not and after that I will give votes and eventually accept an answer. Thank you all for your time!

Comment: Hello guys! I tried this code on another pc and it works with the URL provided by Thai Tran. With my URL won't work. So, my URL is not ok and on the first pc is a problem. I can't figure out what problem is. Thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This URL `returns`  `XML` markup and it is not displayed. You have to add `<pre> </pre>` tag to show XML markup.

```
out.println("<pre>");
String inputLine = "";
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
    {
        out.println(inputLine);
    }
out.println("</pre>");
in.close();
```

You `must` have to use JSTL's `<import/>` instead of Java code in JSPs.

```
<c:import var="xmlData" url="http://your.url" />

<c:out var="${xmlData}"/>
```

Comment: AVD, thank you for answering! I added the pre tags and those imports but still nothing (I'm not familiar with JSP). It's clearly something regarding jsp because if I add System.out.println(inputLine); just below the out.println in while {}  I get the XML in console

Comment: You can share that *url* if it is *possible* or Just try `http://www.google.com` and see what happen?

Comment: I can't share that URL, it's blocked for other users. My IP has permission.
If I replace that URL with google I get this exception:
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host: connect

Comment: The *URL* in code and a *url* in screenshot are not same. Does it throws an exception with `URL` you have added in `screenshot`?

Comment: No, with both URL's I get a return in console but no print on page :)